# SHA512 reverse (Decrypt) of CreateSHAHash function in c#

Tags: c#

How can i Decrypt the encrypted sctring in SHA512

```
static readonly string securityCode = "mJeb44V5grh0pTB6wgepSw==";
encrypted_Text = CreateSHAHash("12345");
public static string CreateSHAHash(string PasswordSHA512)
{
   SHA512Managed sha512 = new SHA512Managed();
        Byte[] EncryptedSHA512 = sha512.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(string.Concat(PasswordSHA512, securityCode)));
        sha512.Clear();
        return Convert.ToBase64String(EncryptedSHA512);
    }
```

Comment: You don't, that's the purpose of a hashing function.

Comment: A hash is not encryption. A hash is one-way. A hash cannot be reversed. A hash is not encryption.

Comment: You cannot decrypt a hashed string rather can convert the other string using the same hash function and compare them.

Comment: One of the main purposes of a hash is nonrepudiation. Two identical values should always produce the same hash (given that other applicable inputs are also constant). A hash does not store the values so it is not possible to reverse the hash to retrieve the values. Hashing allows for things like versioning and secure password management where only the resulting hash is persisted.

Comment: You can create the other function. But that function will return the original text "12345"

Comment: @JayPrakash Why don't you encrypt instead of using hash function. Then this will solve your issue. If not, please explain your use case.

Comment: @ Archit Goyal I can use instead of this. But I want to know the decyption is posible or not.

Comment: @JayPrakash Decryption isn't possible; see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can't "decrypt" a hashed string, because encryption is always a reversible transformation, and hashing is not reversible by design.

To see why hashing isn't reversible without needing to use any math, consider:

- A SHA-512 hash is always exactly the same length.
- That means there are only a finite number of messages it can encode.
- But there are an infinite number of possible messages you might choose to hash.
- By the [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle), you cannot map an infinite number of messages into a finite number of hashes.

∴ You can't reverse a hash to the original message.